# Discrepancies while formatting data using getter in a mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, getter

I am trying to round the balance of `Account` model schema using the `get` keyword while retrieving data from MongoDB using mongoose. 
When I check the value of balance explicitly using `accounts[0].balance`, it does give the rounded number. 
However, the balance property in accounts object is still showing the decimal number. I have pasted the output result of the console below. 
I would like to know why there is a discrepancy in values and also if I can fix it so that the object I return will automatically have the rounded balance.

```
    const Account = mongoose.model(
      "Balances",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 50 },
        balance: { type: Number, get: p => Math.round(p) }
      })
    );

    router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
      const accounts = await Account.find().sort("name");
      console.log("From accounts object: ", accounts);
      console.log("From balance propery: ", accounts[0].balance);
      res.send(accounts);
    });

`From accounts object:  [ 
   { _id: 5d27df2d9e553ec4d48ae7f6,
    name: 'savings',
    balance: 234.8 } 
]
```

From **balance property:  235**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Mongoose getter function with syntax:

```
schema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
schema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });
```

In your case, code will come to:

```
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 50 },
  balance: { type: Number, get: p => Math.round(p) }
});

AccountSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
AccountSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

const Account = mongoose.model(
  "Balances",
  AccountSchema,
);
```

Comment: thanks, I would also like to know how did it round of the balance when I had used accounts[0].balance? If you could help